# How can I solve error in connection string in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2012 database called `box`. I have built an application in C#.

What I want to do is: attach this database file to a client machine to run the application without setting up SQL Server.

1. From mycomputer --> manage--> I stopped the SQL Server service
2. Copy database files (`box.mdf` and `box_log.ldf`) from the application  directory
3. Build connection string to connect with database as:

   ```
   Data Source=BASIM-PC\\SQLSERVER2012;Initial Catalog=box;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=basimbox;Password=f1977
   ```

This works correctly. But

```
Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=box;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=basimbox;Password=f1977
```

causes this error

Comment: Do any of these help? https://www.google.com.au/search?q=SQL+Server+localdb+connection+string

Comment: What ***exactly*** is the error message?? Also: if you want to use `.mdf` database files, ***YOU MUST*** setup SQL Server **Express** on that machine - no way around that.

Comment: marc_s : You are wrong.You do not need SQL Express on machine if you are using SQLClient Class which has the equivalent driver that is in SQL Express.  There are issue with the credentials.SQL Express may correct the credentials but there are other methods to fix the credential issues.  The local PC and Server must be in the same Group (or Group Policy).  Then the user has to be added to the Group on both local and server PC.  Then make sure Server is using windows credentials for database.You should never directly connect to a mdf or ldf file.The server attach the file and owns the file.

Comment: `attach this database file to a client machine` That certainly _sounds_ like they want to run the database as LocalDB.

Comment: thank you very much for replies... but i hope more explain in details : i have database in sql server (sql server authentication ) and work with my application c# in my machine correctly. (how) can i run this application with db to a user machine without installing sql server? and what is the change to connection string?

Answer (score 0):

Check your name Data source: .\SQLSERVER2012.
it's will:
Data Source=.\SQLSERVER2012;Initial Catalog=box;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=basimbox;Password=f1977